# After a Page A/B test has completed, how does one review the test details?

Tags: marketing-definitions

After a Page A/B test has completed, how does one review the test details?

Specifically, I want to see what the losing variation was.  I have reviewed https://doc.sitecore.com/users/82/sitecore-experience-platform/en/create-and-run-page-tests.html.  I also reviewed the "Historical Tests" on the Experience Optimization Dashboard.  There is not a way I can see what the losing test.

Answer (score 0):

Open the page which has the A/B test in experience editor. Then choose optimization tab in editor. There is a button Test Results.

Comment: Thanks - Does this only work when the test is running?

Answer (score 0):

Sitecore XP does not generate reports about the results of historical tests in version 8.2. When one creates a test (e.g. two datasources for the same rendering), it's a good practice to "Manually select winner".  A "winner" datasource is just assigned as the only datasource for a rendering, so a test has served its purpose.

If one wishes to check, what kind of test option they previously had, then review items under the "/sitecore/system/Marketing Control Panel/Test Lab" bucket in your 'master' database.

Reports for historical tests were added in Sitecore XP 9.1.